# Calling aspx page in mvc3 gives error- the view must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am calling an aspx page in  mvc3.

It gives an error

> The view at '~/WebForms/Calendar/Schedule.aspx' must derive from
>   ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or
>   ViewUserControl.

I have added the following code in the global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "Schedule",
    "Classes/ManageSchedule",
    "~/WebForms/Calendar/schedule.aspx"
);
```

and following code in the Classes controller

```
public ActionResult ManageSchedule()
{        
    return View("~/WebForms/Calendar/Schedule.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your aspx pages will not be served out by a controller action.  You should remove the ManageSchedule action from your controller.

In order to route your url /Classes/ManageSchedule to /WebForms/Calendar/schedule.aspx just take your MapPageRoutes that you have, and move it above the routes.MapRoute() that MVC uses to register the controller routes.  The way the routes work is - the first match wins.